# Python script to restart a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I think what I want is straight forward.

Python script to restart my Raspberry Pi after 23 hours and 59 minutes. The reason I am trying to do this, instead of set times with a cron job, is the Pi has no onboard battery for a clock so I don't care what the time is (if connected to internet, it will source current time), just a count down of 23 hours and 59 minutes from the script starting.

This is as far as I have got;

```
def restart():
SendEmail = SendEmail "SYSTEM RESTART", "ncam.py auto restart initiated"      msg['Subject'], body)
command = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now"
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Also I want to send an email to myself with the set parameters as above.

Comment: Just a thought why not create a cron job (or the alike) and execute a python command that will restart your Pi? Otherwise (like below) you have to have a python keep looping and I'm not sure how much cpu/memory it would take up just to run that script.

Comment: why not use a shell script with a `sleep $nearly_a_day; reboot;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to want some variant of this:

```
 import time
 import os
 currentTime = time.time()
 tomorrow = currentTime + 86340000
 while time.time() < tomorrow:
     do.yourCode()
    
 os.system("poweroff")
```

Put something like that in your function and it will do what you want.

Comment: `while time.time() < tomorrow`. See [rtv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560331/python-script-to-restart-a-raspberry-pi#answer-27035266)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply restart raspberry with 'sudo reboot' command. 
Just put this command inside a python code and run it as system command. For example this code count down from 1 to 10 before restart:

```
import time
import os
for i in range(1,10):
       print 'hello',i
       #Do your code here
       time.sleep(1)
os.system("sudo reboot")
```

Use this method to countdown whatever time and restart pi.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change to

```
while time.time() < tomorrow
```

to avoid any potential "miss" of the exact millisecond to match.

Comment: Whilst you are correct (and I must admit that I thought the same), this looks like it is a comment to [stmfunk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560331/python-script-to-restart-a-raspberry-pi#answer-18560417)